# The function $g: \Bbb{Z}_{10} → \Bbb{Z}_{10}$ is defined by $g(x) ≡ 7x + 2 \mod 10$. Find its inverse function.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Solution: From $x = g(y) ≡ 7y + 2 \mod 10$, we obtain

$$y ≡ 7^{−1}(x−2)≡3(x−2) \mod 10$$.

Hence, the inverse function $g^{−1}: \Bbb{Z}_{10} → \Bbb{Z}_{10}$ is defined by $g^{−1}(x) ≡ 3(x − 2) \mod 10$.

I don't understand the steps on how $7^{−1}(x−2)$ is logically equivalent $3(x−2) \mod 10$. I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $3\times7\equiv1\mod 10$

Comment: Because $3$ and $7^{-1}$ are the same thing.  $7^{-1}$ is the residue class $k$ so that $7k\equiv 1 \pmod{10}$.  Because $\gcd(7,10)=1$ there is exactly one such equivalence class.  Testing $7\times (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$ we get $7*3 \equiv 21 \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$.

Comment: Or we can solve with Euclids alogrithe.  $10 = 7+3; 7=2*3 + 1$ so $1= 7-2*3=7-2*(10 -7)=3*7 -2*10$ so $1\equiv 3*7\pmod{10}$.  But .... it doesn't matter *how* you find.  All that matters is that you *do* find $7*3 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$7^{-1}\pmod {10}$ refers to the class $k$ so that $7*k\equiv 1 \pmod {10}$.  If such a class exists.

An $a^{-1} \pmod n$ will exist if and only if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$.

So what is $7^{-1}\pmod {10}$.  What is the solution to $7*k\equiv 1 \pmod {10}$.

We could use Bezout and Euclid's alogorithm to solve $7k + 10a = 1$ but these are such simple and small numbers it's easier to use brute force.

The multiples of $7$ are $7,14\equiv 4, 21\equiv 1, 28\equiv 8, 35\equiv 5, 42\equiv 2, 49\equiv 7, 56\equiv 6, 63\equiv 3, 70 \equiv 0$.

So $7*3 \equiv 21 \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$.

And $7^{-1} = 3\pmod{10}$.

.......

So if $y= g(x) = 7x+2\pmod {10}$ the $g^{-1}$ is the function so that $x =g^{-1}(g(x)) = g^{-1}(y)$ so to find $g^{-1}$ we solve $y = 7x+2\pmod {10}$ for $x$ in terms of $y$.

$y \equiv 7x + 2 \pmod{10}$

$7x \equiv y - 2 \pmod{10}$.

$7^{-1}*7x \equiv 7^{-1}(y-2)\pmod {10}$

$3*7x \equiv 3(y-2)\pmod{10}$

$21x\equiv 3(y-2)\pmod{10}$

$x\equiv 3(y-2)\pmod{10}$

In my a opinion we should distribute the $3(y-2)$

So $x \equiv 3y - 6 \pmod{10}$.

Furthermore I think we should, for aesthetic purposes mostly, consistently use the postive reduced residue system.  $-6\equiv 4 \pmod {10}$

So

$x \equiv 3y + 4 \pmod {10}$

And so $g^{-1}(y) = 3y+4\pmod {10}$ or replacing one variable with  another:

$g^{-1}(x) = 3x + 4\pmod {10}$

...

To verify this we wont to so if $g^{-1}(g(x)) = x$.

$3(7x+2) + 4 \equiv $

$21x + 6 + 4 \equiv $

$21x + 10 \equiv $

$x + 0 \equiv x\pmod{10}$.

And that $g(g^{-1}(x)) = x$.

$7(3x+4) + 2 \equiv $

$21x + 28 + 2 \equiv 21x + 30\equiv$

$x + 0 \equiv x \pmod {10}$.

Answer (score 3):

$3\times 7=21\equiv1\mod10$.

Therefore $7^{-1}\equiv3\mod10$.

That is why $7^{-1}$ can be substituted for $3$ in congruences modulo $10$.

Answer (score 1):

It amounts to finding the inverse of $7$ (mod $10$). This inverse happens to be $3$, i.e. $7^{-1} \pmod{10}= 3\pmod{10}$ since $7\cdot 3\equiv1\pmod{10}$.